# How can I embed an SVG image using JSF/OmniFaces/PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. I have a `@ViewScoped` JSF bean in which I call a JAX-RS service using Jersey.
2. The resource I'm requesting returns a response with content-type `image/svg+xml`.
3. Display it in a Facelet page.

My research so far has lead me to believe:

- `h:graphicImage` (Core JSF) does not support SVG
- `p:graphicImage` (PrimeFaces) does not support SVG
- `o:graphicImage` (OmniFaces) does not support SVG either.

**Is there no way to deliver an SVG image to a facelets page from a backing bean?** The service that serves the SVG images will be extended later to support delivering (among other formats) PNG but I was hoping to utilize the SVG directly.

Comment: Please be specific. Show us what you've tried so far, explain why it's not doing the right thing, instead of asking "how can I do this".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`<o:graphicImage>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage) sets a default content type of `image`, but your browser apparently didn't swallow that for SVG images. As per [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/070e7b53fb551c1d9df457d9d14a6a460b654995), I've for OmniFaces 2.1 added SVG support for `<o:graphicImage dataURI="true">` and I've added a new `type` attribute which allows you to explicitly specify the image type via file extension:

```
<o:graphicImage value="#{bean.image}" type="svg" />
```

In case it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` like this one

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: o:graphicImage 'type' attribute must represent a valid file extension. Encountered an invalid value of 'svg'.

Then it means that your server doesn't recognize it as a registered mime mapping. You should then add a new mime mapping to server's or webapp's `web.xml` as below:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>svg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: OmniFaces is very cool, it's just too bad I can't use it in portlets. I understand it is a technical restriction though.

Comment: BalusC, thank you! I think you've hit the nail on the head here.

I will test the snapshot tomorrow and update here afterwards.

Comment: It works perfectly! 

To clarify, here's my test example:

<o:graphicImage value="#{planBean.sign}" dataURI="true" height="100" width="100" type="svg"/>

The EL expression returns an InputStream.

Comment: You're welcome. Only `dataURI="true"` should not be necessary in this construct (relatively expensive). If you would still stick to `dataURI="true"`, then `type="svg"` should not be necessary.

Comment: From your doc:

"When not rendered as data URI, the InputStream or byte[] property must point to a stateless @ApplicationScoped bean (both JSF and CDI scopes are supported)."

This is why I enabled it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but can you use JSF's `ui:include`? Something like this:

```
<ui:include src="assets/img/fileFromJersey.svg" />
```

Comment: As far as I understand, OP has the image only in flavor of `byte[]` or `InputStream`.

Comment: @BalusC Yeah I guess this wouldn't work if it wasn't written to the disk.