# How can I supply style selector to SVG (byte[]) when I use OmniFaces graphicImage tag?

Tags: jsf, svg, jsf-2.2, omnifaces, graphicimage

Follow-up to [How to embed SVG graphics properly in JSF application using OmniFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582422/how-to-embed-svg-graphics-properly-in-jsf-application-using-omnifaces)

I'm using the OmniFaces 2.1 snapshot in order to output SVG files from byte[] arrays. I need to suffix **#a** on SVG URL's in order to activate a CSS style inside the SVG.

Example img:

```
<img src="/web/javax.faces.resource/ApplicationBean_getImageById_svg.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.graphic&amp;v=0&amp;p=106.1%23a">
```

As you can see, my **#a** is appended at the right side of the URL as **%23a**.

If this had been a regular URL it would be

```
<img src="106.1.svg#a" />
```

It would then pick the CSS style and, in my case, paint the background of this sign yellow.

I'm really hoping BalusC comes to my rescue here. Heh. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/a755e9a225b50caa04eafa5599ec195637c74035), the `<o:graphicImage>` got a new `fragment` attribute. This should enable you to pass [SVG view modes via URL fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG). It's available in today's [2.1 SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.1-SNAPSHOT/).

E.g.

```
<o:graphicImage value="#{bean.svg(imageId)}" 
    type="svg" fragment="svgView(viewBox(0,200,1000,1000))" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the fragment comes to my rescue. Here's an example SVG:

`<style>
#a {
    fill: blue;
}
#a:target {
    fill:red;
}
</style>

<rect id="a" width="100" height="100" />
`
When '''#a''' is appended to the svg url, this causes the browser to trigger the conditional style. I can't see how the fragment attribute can help.

Comment: It appends the fragment to the generated URL (like as how `<h:link fragment>` works). Just tryout the current snapshot with `<o:graphicImage ... fragment="a" />`.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks a bunch, BalusC. Any idea on when 2.1 is to be finalized?

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully end this month or early April.